# What if a value is equal to the pivot in a quick sort algorithm

Tags: python, quicksort

## What if a value is equal to the pivot in a quick sort algorithm?

Hi guys, I've decided to take It upon myself to recreate some popular algorithms so I can learn some and add It to my portfolio of code on *GitHub*. My question is as follows.

In a quick sorting algorithm we pick a pivot from which we start splitting the list form correct? I've chosen to pick the value in the middle using this line of code `array[len(array)//2]`. Then I will split the list into two. Using the for loop below.

```
for i in array:
   if i > pivot:
      sorted[1][len(sorted[1])] = i
   if i < pivot:
      sorted[0][len(sorted[0])] = i
```

Now what if value i is equal to the pivot. How do I handle It and to I put It in the lower part or upper part?

## What I followed

I followed [Computerphiles tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XE4VP_8Y0BU) on YouTube where they explain the Quick Sort algorithm. They did not bring this *issue* up so that is why I'm asking here. Now the answer may be very simple but It might have just flown above my head. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Values equal to the pivot you put between the values less than it and the values greater than it.

Comment: So your implying that I make a third part in the list and that is where I put all the values equal to the pivot?

Comment: Yes I thought of doing that but I had a belief that It would mess the algorithm up. Thanks!

Comment: There are actually several different algorithms for partitioning the values.  You can read about some of them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm).

Comment: Quicksort normally swaps values rather than copy them to new arrays. With both of the common partition algorithms, Lomuto and Hoare, elements equal to the pivot can end up anywhere, and may not end up in their sorted position until a base case of a single element is reached. As for performance, as the number of duplicate elements increase, Lomuto approaches worst case O(n^2) time complexity, while Hoare approaches best case O(n log2(n)) time complexity.